# simple keyboard popup and key style

Tags: android, keyboard, popup

Using an Android custom keyboard project from another site, I've modified it.  However, I haven't figured out how to get the "popup" keys to display the correct lowercase or uppercase character.  Below is the keyboard.  The key becomes yellow when selected.  When the popup key opens, the popup characters for both upper and lower cases open.  How and where do I write the code so that the appropriate popup key goes only with the selected character: that is, only the ogonek lowercase "a" with the lowercase "a"; and only the uppercase ogonek "A" with the uppercase "A"?
Can this same method be used to reduce the size of the popup key characters, dim them and place them above the appropriate displayed key?
Thank you for your attention.

[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/detNj.png)

"qwerty.xml" fragment for "a" key

```
    <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="60dp"
>
    <Row>
    <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="Ąą" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
</Row>
```

"popup.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:keyHeight="10%">
</Keyboard>
```

Comment: You might wanna look at Google's LatinIME repo: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/.  They handle all such cases in that code.